# AWS Api Gateway Custom Domain Name with undefined stage

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to set up a Custom Domain Name in AWS API Gateway where **callers have to specify explicitly the stage name after any base path name**. It is something I did in the past but now it seems that, since AWS updated the console interface, it is no more possible.
The final url should be like:

https://example.com/{basePath}/{stage}/function

- I tried using the console, but stage is now a mandatory field (chose from a drop-down).
- I tried using AWS CLI, but stage is again a mandatory field
  `aws: error: the following arguments are required: --stage`
- I tried using Boto3, following the documentation (https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/apigateway.html#APIGateway.Client.create_base_path_mapping) but, even if stage can be specified as 'none' (*The name of the API's stage that you want to use for this mapping. Specify '(none)' if you want callers to explicitly specify the stage name after any base path name.*), doing this returns an error:
  `botocore.errorfactory.BadRequestException: An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the CreateBasePathMapping operation: Invalid stage identifier specified`

What is funny (or frustrating) is that I have some custom domain names created with the old console and that are perfectly working, without any stage defined.

Comment: You could do `https://{basePath}.example.com/{stage}/function`. I don't think you can do it the other way through API gateway. Maybe though some proxy?

Comment: Thanks, but this is not an option because, as stage became mandatory, its value is implicit. So the final url becomes `https://example.com/{basePath}/function` or, as you suggested, `https://{basePath}.example.com/function`. The difference between the two is just a matter of taste. The real problem here is that you have to declare stage.

Comment: I think Cloudfront may offer a solution for this. Are you willing to try it or have you looked on that side?

Comment: You are specifying `'(none)'` and not `'none'`, correct?

Comment: Correct. Honestly I tried many different nones: `None`, `'none'`, `'(none)'` and so on. Unfortunately without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is still possible to specify only the "API ID" and "Path" and leave out the "stage" parameter. I have tried this both from the console and the CLI:

- From console: The "Stage" setting is a drop-down as you mentioned, but can be left blank (don't select anything). If you did select a stage, delete the API mapping and add it again
- From CLI: Just tried this as well and works fine for me on CLI version `aws-cli/1.18.69 Python/3.7.7 Darwin/18.7.0 botocore/1.16.19`

```
$ aws apigateway create-base-path-mapping --domain-name **** --rest-api-id *** --base-path test
{
    "basePath": "test",
    "restApiId": "***"
}
```

Comment: Honestly I don't know why but if I don't select the stage setting, the console doesn't allow me to save the API mapping.
About AWS CLI, I confirm I was using the wrong parameters (`aws apigatewayv2 create-api-mapping ...`). Your solution worked like a charm.
Finally AWS confirmed there is a bug in Boto3.